# Can't get all data from API using post method

Tags: android, post, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader

I can't get complete data from server by using API.

I use AsyncTask and HttpURLConnection to get data, it can work.

But when server return more data, I found that I can't get complete data.

How can I fix that, thank you.

Here is my code. and in these code, I can't get data of `jsonArray_banner`, it always return null array.

```
public class JSONTask_Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private String deviceId, os, ver;

        public JSONTask_Login(String _deviceId, String _os, String _ver) {
            this.deviceId = _deviceId;
            this.os = _os;
            this.ver = _ver;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String SERVER_WS_URL = params[0];

                parameter.clear();
                parameter.put("deviceId", deviceId);
                parameter.put("os",  os);
                parameter.put("ver",  ver);

                return ApiCall.postWebserviceCall(SERVER_WS_URL, parameter); // POST.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                if (result != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                    code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                    msg = jsonObject.getString("msg");

                    if (Integer.valueOf(code) == 0) {
                        // 1st block.
                        JSONObject jsonObject_userInfo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("userInfo");
                        ....

                        // 2nd block.    
                        JSONArray jsonArray_first = jsonObject.getJSONArray("anonymous_first_name");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray_first.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject_anonFirst = jsonArray_first.getJSONObject(i);
                            ...
                        }

                        // 3rd block.
                        JSONArray jsonArray_Second = jsonObject.getJSONArray("anonymous_second_name");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray_Second.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject_anonSecond = jsonArray_Second.getJSONObject(i);
                            ...
                        }

                        // 4th block.
                        JSONArray jsonArray_Head = jsonObject.getJSONArray("anonymous_head");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray_Head.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject_anonHead = jsonArray_Head.getJSONObject(i);
                            ...
                        }

                        // 5th block.
                        JSONArray jsonArray_list = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts_group_list");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray_list.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject_list = jsonArray_list.getJSONObject(i);
                            ...
                        }

                        // 6th block.
                        // I can get data of this block, jsonArray_banner always return null array.
                        JSONArray jsonArray_banner = jsonObject.getJSONArray("banner_home");

                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray_banner.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject_banner = jsonArray_banner.getJSONObject(i);
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        return;
                } else
                    return;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my **`ApiCall` code:**

```
class ApiCall {
    static String postWebserviceCall(String URL, LinkedHashMap<String, String> params) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(URL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            if (params != null)
                writer.write(getPostDataString(params));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            InputStream iStream;

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                iStream = conn.getInputStream();
            else
                iStream = conn.getErrorStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                Log.e("test", line);
            }

            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    static String getWebserviceCall(String URL, LinkedHashMap<String, String> params) {
        ...
    }

    private static String getPostDataString(LinkedHashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        boolean first = true;

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

}
```

Here is my api structure:

```
{
    code: 0,
    msg: "",
    userInfo: {
        token: "token",
        nick: "user",
        head: "Head/Default.png",
        ...
    },
    anonymous_first_name: [
        {
            id: "1",
            nick_name: "one",
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            nick_name: "two",
        },
        ...
    ],
    anonymous_second_name: [
        {
            id: "1",
            nick_name: "one",
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            nick_name: "two",
        },
        ...
    ],
    anonymous_head: [
        {
            id: "1",
            head: "System/AnonHead/star_head_01.png",
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            head: "System/AnonHead/star_head_02.png",
        },
        ...
    ],
    posts_group_list: [
        {
            post_group: "1",
            title: "title",
            short_title: "stitle",
            icon: "System/Classify/classify_01_food.png",
            img: "",
            color_code: "#E53737",
        },
        {
            post_group: "2",
            title: "title",
            short_title: "stitle",
            icon: "System/Classify/classify_02_travel.png",
            img: "",
            color_code: "#3C9BA5",
        },
        ...
    ],
    banner_home: [
        {
            title: "title",
            gid: "25",
            url: "url",
            banner: "imgurl",
            start_time: "2019-08-30 00:00:00",
            end_time: "2021-08-30 00:00:00",
        },
        {
            title: "title",
            gid: "24",
            url: "url",
            banner: "imgurl",
            start_time: "2019-08-30 00:00:00",
            end_time: "2021-08-30 00:00:00",
        },
        ...
    ],
}
```

Comment: can you show the structure of the response? (json)

Comment: @FranciscoBarrios I add in my post, thank you!